# Why can't gulp-shell set environment variables?

Tags: bash, gulp, gulp-shell

I have the following simple `gulpfile.js` script:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');

gulp.task('run-me', shell.task([
  'export sweet_param=5',
  'echo $sweet_param'
]));
```

The problem is that `$sweet_param` variable is not printed.

When run on Windows 8.1 under Git Bash it fails with the message:

```bash
[16:51:06] Starting 'run-me'...
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[16:51:06] 'run-me' errored after 29 ms
[16:51:06] Error in plugin 'gulp-shell'
Message:
    Command `export sweet_param=5` failed with exit code 1
```

In case of Linux the task is executed without errors but the blank line is printed instead of expected value:

```bash
[16:49:32] Starting 'run-me'...

[16:49:32] Finished 'run-me' after 26 ms
```

If the commands from the task are executed manually in bash on both operating systems, `5` is successfully echoed.

Software used:

- gulp 3.8.11
- gulp-shell 0.4.1
- Node.js v0.12.2
- bash version 3.1.20(4)-release (i686-pc-msys) on Windows
- bash version 4.3.33(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) on Linux.

What's the catch here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash allows environment variables only to exist during one bash session. When you type

`export sweet_param=5`

`sweet_param` just exists as long as the bash is open. Close your shell, and `sweet_param`'s gone.

`gulp-shell` takes a command per line, but for every line, it boots up another bash: open bash >> execute line >> terminate bash >> next. Therefore, after every line you have there, all the previously set params are gone.

Try:

```
gulp.task('run-me', shell.task([
   'export sweet_param=5 && echo $sweet_param'
]));
```

to see that if you have all the executions in one line, your parameters will sta.

To write it a little more pretty, you could use something like that:

```
gulp.task('run-me', shell.task([
   'export sweet_param=5',
   'echo $sweet_param'
].join(' && '));
```

As for the Win problem: Git bash is still no Unix shell. You should try Cygwin or consorts to make that work.

Comment: That makes perfect sense!

What's interesting about Git Bash for Windows, though, is that the `export` command works if I input it manually into the console.

Comment: Might be that *gulp-shell" does not use the environment where it's called from but rather one where it's sure that it exists. Which would be the Windows command line.